# Not able to transfer variables from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried sending data stored in an array(emp) using ajax and other string variables like 'gtotal' in code but data has not been transferred to the PHP file. It doesn't show any error but when I removed the isset() function it says unidentified index. I tried with different variables but no luck so far. Console function is working in HTML file and returning the values passed but data has not been collected in PHP file-like return value of $_POST shows empty array.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script >

          $('#btn').click(function(){
             var grandtotal=document.getElementById("gt");
                var x =grandtotal.textContent;
                var gtotal= String(x);;
var emp={};
emp.name=gtotal;

             if(x=== '₹0'){
             alert("Add to your cart")}
             else{  $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "connect2.php",
        data: emp,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

        }
        });
              // location.href='connect2.php'


             }});
            </script>
```

```html
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['gtotal']))
{
    $gtotal = $_POST['gtotal'];
       echo $gtotal;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show what `print_r($_POST)` is outputting?

Comment: You are sending the data using `array` `var emp={};` you need to check how `$_POST` is received

Comment: Array ( ) -----this is the output of print_r($_POST)

Comment: We know its `Array()` We need to see what exactly you get, can you do a screenshot or copy paste the result ?

Comment: That is the result. Only "Array ( )" is written on the screen.

Comment: Just to note, you've included jQuery twice in your page. That's not necessary and can even cause problems sometimes. Only keep the most recent version

Comment: I removed one but no difference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no item called gtotal is being sent in the $_POST.

Do a var_dump($_POST) to check exactly what is being sent.

You asked for an object to be sent which has an item name. If you see that in the dump then you need to use $_POST['name'] not $_POST['gtotal']

Comment: I checked it shows an empty array. I also tried to input a string in place of gtotal but that is also not passed.

Comment: Could you try sending the data as a string and see exactly what the var_dump gives you?

Comment: It is still empty at php page. But console.log(data ) is returning the proper values at console of HTML page